# How to hide/show more text within a certain length in table grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[image: Table Grid Image]

In the above image onclick of  *...view* link i am displaying the popup which contains description. And below are query which i have.

> 1. How can i display the link on stretching of column width till specific character length.

Ex: Consider the Course description length is 50 character ,so on stretching of column till 49th character i need to display the link, after exceeding the character 50 the link should get disappear.

```
            require(["jslib/require/text!js/isd/templates/test.html"], function (FooterTemplate) {
                if(value !== null){
                    element.html("<div class='course-container'>"+value.substr(0,18)+"</div>");

                    var iconBind = $("<a class='course-link'  href=\"javascript:\" >  " + "...view" + "</a>");
                    var body = "<div style='height:200px;width:400px'>"+value+"</div>";

                    iconBind.bind("click", {
                        model: model
                    }, function () {
                        var TestApp = require("js/app/TestApp");
                        var ModalLayout = require("js/common/layouts/ModalLayout");
                        var modalLayout = new ModalLayout({
                            title: "Course Description",
                            footerTemplate: FooterTemplate
                        });
                        TestApp.getView().getRegion('modalRegion').show(modalLayout);
                        modalLayout.getRegion('modalContentRegion').show(body);
                    });
                    element.find('.course-container').append(iconBind);
                }
            });
        },
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how are you currently hiding/displaying the text on stretch?

Comment: Currently i have configured specific length for 18 characters length. So it will not display after 18 characters where i have provided the view link.

Comment: I was under the impression that you already implemented the text string size increase on stretch, so your question includes the stretching functionality right? You can use `ellipsis`.

Comment: Yes you are right.. instead of fixed length it should be dynamically show and hide the link.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to implement this using `text-overflow: ellipsis;`.
Just add this css to your 'course-container' class :

```
.course-container {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

That way it will display more text as you stretch the container and will remove '...' when fully displayed.

Now regarding the `view` link,
You can change the ellipsis behavior and instead of showing '...' you will show '... view' (with your popup link).

Or (A better way) you can check if the content is overflowing :

```
element = document.getElementById('your-element-id');
if (element.scrollWidth > element.clientWidth)
```

if true display your 'view' link.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on how to change ellipsis behavior and instead of showing '...' you will show '... view' (with your popup link). because I am trying this approach but not meeting the result.

Comment: You can search for "Truncate html to Ellipsis", but i really think you should use the second option i suggested.